# wordpress "rest_invalid_handler" error

Tags: api

I want to write some api and api callbacks are static functions within multiple classes.
But when I call api I get the following error:
‍‍‍

```
{
    "code": "rest_invalid_handler",
    "message": "The handler for the route is invalid",
    "data": {
        "status": 500
    }
}
```

my `api action`:

```php
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('doctor/v1', 'find/best', [
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'Find::best',
    ]);
});
```

my `find` class:

```php
class Find
{
    public static function best(WP_REST_Request $request)
    {
        var_dump($request);
    }
}
```

my `autoloader`:

```php
<?php
class ShaadiSearchDoctorAutoloader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'sdAutoload'));
    }

    public function sdAutoload($class_name)
    {
        $file = $this->convertClassToFile($class_name);

        if (is_file($file) && file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)) {
            include $file;
        }
    }

    public function convertClassToFile($class_name)
    {
        $class = strtolower($class_name);
        $class = 'class-' . $class;
        $file_name = $class . '.php';

        $file_path = PLUGIN_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name;
        return $file_path;
    }
}

new ShaadiSearchDoctorAutoloader();
```

Comment: you must define a static method as `'callback' => ['Find', 'best'],`

Comment: Is the `Find` class namespaced?